# Why We Need To Repaint JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d

The problem is when you draw a JPanel like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor (Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(10,10,200,50);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(50,50,50,50);
}
```

So if when a JPanel is created it draw a cyan rectangle and a red oval.
The problem is that if you want to move the oval for example, you must repaint the whole panel!

How can I make a 2D object and make it  movable and changeable without the need to redraw the whole panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) to understand the painting process.

You don't "have" to repaint the whole panel if you don't want to, you can use [`JPanel#repaint(int, int, int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) which allows you to specify the area you want repainted.

Now, remember, if you will need to paint the area that use to contain the oval and then paint the area that it now resides, this makes sure that the previous location is updated as well, otherwise you will get ghosting...

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testball;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestBall {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBall();
    }

    public TestBall() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int x = 100 - 10;
        private int y = 100 - 10;
        private int delta = 4;

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Replace existing area...
                    repaint(x, y, 21, 21);

                    x += delta;
                    if (x + 20 >= getWidth()) {
                        x = getWidth() - 20;
                        delta *= -1;
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                        x = 0;
                        delta *= -1;
                    }
                    repaint(x, y, 21, 21);
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawOval(x, y, 20, 20);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to repaint if you have your object in a new order. Repaint is also called by default if you minimize and maximize your window. One possibility to make a 2D object that automatically updates the panel while moving is to use the observer pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern